# regex matching "not anything of two characters"

Tags: regex, pattern-matching

This is what I am trying to do:

Text:
-one oneitis -two +three+four+five -six-seven-eight -nine then eleven +twelve thirteen

I want to match:

1. -one oneitis
2. -two
3. +three
4. +four
5. +five
6. -six-seven-eight
7. -nine then eleven
8. +twleve thirteen

Basically, ignore matching '-' within words, but matching '+' if they exist, and ' -'

This is the regex I am using: /([-+][^+]+)/

I want to essentially do [^(+)&( -)]+

Or, match anything that is not '+' nor ' -' <- that is (space and minus)

Is there some way to do this?

Thanks in advance!
(linking some tools http://rubular.com/)

Comment: Even if it's not homework, the rules are obviously more complicated than "basically ignore matching + within words". And you haven't sufficiently constrained your problem, so any set of rules we can guess from your example may well be wrong. I suggest you sit down and define exactly what your matching rules are. By then, you possibly won't even need our help anymore.

Comment: unfortunately, it is not... I liked homework...

Comment: essentially, I want to have the 'in between' text/data. The one's between "+" and "-" with the exception of "-" if it is surrounded by characters. " -" is ok

Answer (score 3):

Solution.

```
    ([-+](?:[^ ][-]|[ ][^-+]|[^ +-])+)
```

http://rubular.com/r/fTSm0pjvEX

Comment: In other words, use the alternation operator as your "logic gate."

Answer (score 1):

One option is to split by `\+|\B-`: http://rubular.com/r/tC2zTWZI4v

The splits by every `+`, and `-` that are after a space (or any non alphanumeric character).

That means it will not split in some cases, for example `+a b-c` will not be split.

If you do want to match your words, and want to split in that case, you can try:

```
[+-]([^\s+]*[^+-]*)
```

http://rubular.com/r/TqQEAoJ2Yv

Comment: Thanks Kobi, but I was looking to match words with no splitting. I was having issues with the word matching in combination with the flags. I got the answer now, but thanks anyways!